# How to customize SPI in keycloak?

Tags: jboss7.x, customization, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am new to keycloak.
With my team we are using Red Hat Single Sign-On 7.0  with Keycloak 1.9.8.
I need to customize this a little bit. We support different languages and
actually some messages we want are not displayed.
For example the message in Recaptcha is not in the expected language.
I found an example how to register Google Recaptcha and how  to add validation
of form elements on the page:
*https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-developer-guide/content/topics/auth-spi.html*
So I suppose if I will register my own Recaptcha I can specify what message
I want to display.
As written I need to deploy my jar (*just copy it to the
standalone/configuration/providers directory*)
First,  I didn't find the *providers *directory in the configuration so I created
one where I copied my jar and I then restarted my server. Then I tried to add my
FormAction to the registration Flow, however I don't see any diffrence in admin
console. I don't think my jar was deployed( I am new to jboss)
I found there also another way to deploy jar: *put jar in Keycloak deploy
directory* but I don't understand what is meant by the "Keycloak deploy/
directory" mentioned in the documentation.

Another change I want to do is:  in reset password page add an email
validation.
I found some example.  *Keycloak is designed to cover most use-cases
without requiring custom code, but we also want it to be customizable. To
achive this **Keycloak has a number of Service Provider Interfaces (SPI)
which you can implement your own providers for*.
Could you please recommend one which I should implement for this goal.

I will appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Comment: Try to add in the standalon/deployment folder. It is expoding and trying to deploy. I can see it in the logs